# TikZ: Accessing coordinates from coded points

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, coordinates

Consider the code below.  In the `scope` environment, I am using a clip to keep the ellipse between the points.  From reading, I know with the `let` command I can access the coordinates of the points by defining them in the let command `\p2 = (P2)`.  Can I access the coordinates to use in the clip?

The goal is so if I change `P2`, the clip will change too.

```
  \documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc, decorations.markings, intersections}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    dot/.style = {outer sep = +0pt, inner sep = +0pt, shape = circle, draw = black, label = {#1}},
    small dot/.style = {minimum size = 1pt, dot = {#1}},
    big dot/.style = {minimum size = 2pt, dot = {#1}},
    line join = round, line cap = round, >=triangle 45
    ]
    \node[ fill = black, big dot = {below: \(F\)}] (F) at (0, 0) {};
    \node[ fill = black, big dot = {below: \(P_1\)}] (P1)  at (2, 0) {};
    \node[ fill = black, big dot = {above right=.25cm:\(P_2\)}] (P2) at (-2, 2) {};    

    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}                  
    \begin{scope}[decoration = {markings,
        mark = at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}
      }]
      \clip (2, 0) -- (-2, 0) -- (-2, 2.2) -- (2, 2.2) -- cycle;
      \draw[name path global = ellp, postaction = decorate] let
        \p0 = ($(P2) - (F)$),
        \p1 = ($(P1) - (P2)$)
      in (P2|-P1) ++ (\x1, 0) arc (0:100: \x1 and \y0);                                         
  \end{scope}
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

\path[name path = aux1] (P2) circle [radius = 1bp];
\draw[name intersections = {of = ellp and aux1}, -latex] (P2) --
($(intersection-2)!.75cm!(intersection-1)$);
\draw [-latex] (P2) --
($(P2)!0.75cm!-90:($(intersection-2)!.75cm!(intersection-1)$)$);


  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean? You can use `(\p2)` as well as `\x2` and `\y2` (in the canvas) after you add `\p2 = (P2)`, though I would add this first, so that you can use `\p2` in the calculation of the other nodes, too. — Or do you mean something like `\clip (P1) rectangle (P2);`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel so I can just go into the clip coordinates and add `\x2` and `\y2` as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering directly **your question**: yes, you can use the `let..in` syntax as part of a `\clip` command. For example:

```
\clip let \p1=(P2) in (\x1,\y1) rectangle (P1);
```

This will allow you to do some arithmetic on the individual x and y coordinates, but you have a drawback: you need to specify the units of the constants you add or substract, as for example:

```
\clip let \p1=(P2) in (\x1 + 0.5cm, \y1) rectangle (P1);
```

if you don't specify the units, tikz will use `pt` as the default. And since points are very small, you won't see any change simply with `\x1+0.5`.

Specifying the units is not optimal, since it will make the figure not easily scalable. If you give the option `x=5mm`, for example, all dimensionless coordinates will be halved, but your `0.5cm` constant will not.

A **better solution** is to use *calc expressions*, as in:

```
\clip ($(P2)+(0.5, 0)$) rectangle (P1);
```

this not only has a clearer syntax, but also works without specifying the dimensions of the `(0.5, 0)` constant, and thus makes the image easily scalable. Note that to use these kind of expressions `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` is required (but you had it anyway).

Comment: Well, whether it is a better solution to use `calc expressions` I’ll leave that undecided. But it is certainly better to use the `rectangle` path operator here. Without `calc`, you can also do `\clip [shift=(right:.5)] P2) rectangle (P1);` or `{(.5,0)}` of course. (This is also true for the second code snipped so you don’t need to specify the unit for the `0.5cm` part making it flexible to changes in the coordinate system.)